# How to read a set of parameters from the application.yml file

Tags: java, spring-boot

In the file application.yml several parameters are specified the usual parameters

```
receiver:
  address: address@gmail.com
```

I read it this way:

```
  @Value("${receiver.address}")
  private static String receiverAddres;
```

But how to read such a set?:

```
sender.smtp: {'mail.host':'smtp.gmail.com','mail.smtp.port':'465'}
```

I tried to do this

```
@Value("${sender.smtp.mail.host}")
public static String smptHost;
```

When the application starts, it outputs:

```
smptHost = null
```

Comment: This wouldn't be a set but a nested object/map so I'd assume you can use something like `${sender.smtp.mail.host}` etc.

Comment: I have an IDE swearing at such a record

Comment: Having another look this seems to be a [YAML flow mapping](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2790832). I'm not sure Spring Boot supports the full YAML spec but I'd assume so. Is it just your IDE that's complaining or the application as well?

Comment: Yes, the IDE throws an error on such an entry
${sender.smtp.mail.host}

Comment: You already stated your IDE is complaining. What about the application itself? What happens if just try to compile and run the code from the command line?

Comment: It works, but when you start the app, it gives you: smptHost = null. I added to the question text

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `application.xml`, but I will assume you mean `application.yml`.

Using `@Value` is convenient, but it is in most cases better to use [Type-safe Configuration Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties).

Declare a class like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("email.settings")
public class MyEmailSettings {
  private ReceiverSettings receiver = new ReceiverSettings();
  private SenderSettings sender = new SenderSettings();

  // getter and setters

  public static class ReceiverSettings {
    private String address;
    
    // getter and setters
  }

  public static class SenderSettings {
    private String host;
    private String port;
  }
}
```

Then you can use a YAML like this:

```
email.settings:
  receiver:
    address: 'address@gmail.com'
  sender:
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com'
    port: '465'
```

By using such a `ConfigurationProperties` class, you will also get validation in the most IDE's to ensure there are no typo's in your YAML file.

Comment: no, I can't change the file application.yml. I need to read this particular line:
sender.smtp: {'mail.host':'smtp.gmail.com','mail.smtp.port':'465'}

Comment: @alexSerg why can't you change that line? Normally it would be your application that dictates the content and format of any configuration files.

Comment: I'm not the only one writing this app, so I can't just change any files. But if this is a very big problem, then I can report it and ask you to redo this code. But I do not know maybe this is not a problem, but I just do not have enough knowledge to deal with it

Comment: I would suggest to talk to the other developers on the project and discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `application.yaml` add a list like the example below:

```yaml
test:
  list: one, two, three
```

when you need to call/use the list import it and use it like this:

```java
public class RandomClass {
    @Value("${test.list}")
    public String[] list;
    
    pulic void printFirstValue() {
        System.out.println(list[0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't change the file application.yml. And in my case, two fields: name and value

Comment: Hmm if it should not be changed then it's probably used somewhere in the code. The answer is probably there look where it's been used and how. If it's not used then changing it should not be a problem.